# загрузка классов в реестр на php

Tags: php

использую реестр:

```
class Registry {
    public static $objects = array();
    protected static $instance;

    /*protected function __construct() { //метод для автодобавления классов в файл конфигурации
        global $config;

        foreach ($config['pages'] as $name => $obj) {
            self::$objects[$name] = new $obj;
        }
    }*/

    public static function instance () {
        if(self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if (!isset(self::$objects[$name])) {
            self::$objects[$name] = new $value;
        }
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (is_object(self::$objects[$name])) {
            return self::$objects[$name];
        }
    }
}
```

для того чтоб пользоваться нужными классами в необходимое время и необходимом месте кода, далее загрузчик всех дополнительных классов из папок libs и models:

```
    class LoadClasses {
    private $app;

    public function __construct() {
        return $this->app = Registry::instance();
    }

    public function LoadLibs ($dir) {

        if($handle = opendir($dir)){

            while(false !== ($file_dir = readdir($handle))) {
                if($file_dir != "." && $file_dir != ".."){

                    $data = file_get_contents($dir.'/'.$file_dir);
                    preg_match_all('/class [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*/', $data, $matches);

                    if (!empty($matches[0])) {
                         foreach ($matches[0] as $val) {
                             $className = 'lib_'.substr($val, 6);
                             $this->app->$className = substr($val, 6);
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function LoadModels ($dir) {

        if($handle = opendir($dir)){

            while(false !== ($file_dir = readdir($handle))) {
                if($file_dir != "." && $file_dir != ".."){

                    $data = file_get_contents($dir.'/'.$file_dir);
                    preg_match_all('/class [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*/', $data, $matches);

                    if (!empty($matches[0])) {
                         foreach ($matches[0] as $val) {
                             $classNameMods = 'mod_'.substr($val, 6);
                             $this->app->$classNameMods = substr($val, 6);
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$loader = new LoadClasses();
```

в чем собственно проблема, все файлы с кассами из каталога libs успешно обрабатываются и заносятся в реестр и после этого я могу с ними работать когда мне это нужно и где, но вот с классами из каталога models проблема что они выводят результат даже если не обращаться к этому классу
в файле индекс вызываю загрузчики классов:

```
$loader->LoadLibs(WWW.'/libs');
$loader->LoadModels(WWW.'/models');
```

пример класса из каталога libs:

```
class validateForms {
    public function FormData ($data) {
        echo $data . ' Fuck! ';
    }
}
```

пример класса из каталоога models:

```
class MainModel extends Model {
    public function mainModel () {
        echo __CLASS__." model! ";
    }
}
```

почему классы из models выводят результат даже если к ним не обращаться??? будно сами собой!

Answer (score 1):

Ну потому что у вас название функции `mainModel` а название класса `MainModel`.
Такую ситуацию `PHP` воспринимает равносильно `__construct`.

Comment: да, спасибо, верно, я тоже заметил это сразу после того как опубликовал вопрос